# Accessing third party location url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, dom, react-router

I have an application where you need to give permission to access files. The user clicks a button which opens a pop up window for the user to log in and allow access. The pop up window then redirects to a url which contains a **code**. I need to get this **code** from the url, so I can then send it to my API.

The issue I am having is I continue to get this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

A preview of the code is as follows:

```js
var windowReference;
    const openAccessWindow = async () => {
        if (windowReference == null || windowReference.closed) {
            windowReference = window.open(
                'https://sandbox-api.some_more_information',
                'Records', 'popup');
console.log(windowReference.location.href);

        } else {
            windowReference.focus()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any frames in your code, but since you mentioned them, read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#scripting

Comment: If that isn't helpful read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @RandyCasburn So I actually don't use an frame anywhere. this is the only area i create the pop up window.